# Vue.js with TypeScript getting data from Twig error Property does not exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, twig

I'm having trouble printing out the data from Twig template on my Symfony app. I am using Vue.js with TypeScript enabled.

main.ts:

```
import HeaderNav from './components/HeaderNav.vue'
new HeaderNav({el: '.headnav'});
```

HeaderNav.vue:

```
<template>
<div class="headnav headnav-fixed z-depth-1">
    {{test}}
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Emit, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
    props: {
        test: {
            type: String,
            default: "{}"
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log(this.test);
    }
    })
    export default class HeaderNav extends Vue {}
</script>
```

header.html.twig:

```
<div class="headnav" data-test="hello"></div>
```

I get this error while compiling:

> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

Any ideas that am I doing wrong? I am thinking that calling the component HeaderNav first might be the problem, because it instantly overrides the element with class 'headnav', but I am trying to create the components only for separate elements on my site, I don't want to put whole application into Vue.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the problem is with you defined props.

In Vue with typescript you need to use props like this:

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  name: "HeaderNav"
})
export default class HeaderNav extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: '' }) test!: string;

  created(){
    console.log(this.test)
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

For more information checkout this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/

Comment: Thanks. Now it compiles fine, but still the variable is empty. I guess the problem is how it is defined in twig file.